# How could I expose data using var_dump on Eloquent ORM Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to php development and I want to use var_dump to debug my php program on the client side.

```
 $test= Admin::where("EPANTHERID","=",$email);
        var_dump($test);die();
```

On the client side, I receive this

```
bject(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)[187]  protected 'query' =>     object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)[186]      protected 'connection' =>         object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection)[179]          protected 'pdo' =>             object(PDO)[180]              ...          protected 'readPdo' => null          protected 'reconnector' =>             object(Closure)[185]              ...          protected 'queryGrammar' =>             object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar)[181]              ...          protected 'schemaGrammar' => null          protected 'postProcessor' =>             object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\MySqlProcessor)[182]              ...          protected 'events' =>             object(Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher)[14]              ...          protected 'paginator' =>             object(Closure)[184]              ...          protected 'cache' =>             object(Closure)[183]              ...          protected 'fetchMode' => int 8          protected 'transactions' => int 0          protected 'queryLog' =>             array (size=0)              ...          protected 'loggingQueries' => boolean true          protected 'pretending' => boolean false          protected 'database' => string 'xinwen_development' (length=18)          protected 'tablePrefix' => string '' (length=0)          protected 'config' =>             array (size=9)              ...      protected 'grammar' =>         object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar)[181]          protected 'selectComponents' =>             array (size=11)              ...          protected 'tablePrefix' => string '' (length=0)      protected 'processor' =>         object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\MySqlProcessor)[182]      protected 'bindings' =>         array (size=5)          'select' =>             array (size=0)              ...          'join' =>             array (size=0)              ...          'where' =>             array (size=1)              ...          'having' =>             array (size=0)              ...          'order' =>             array (size=0)              ...      public 'aggregate' => null      public 'columns' => null      public 'distinct' => boolean false      public 'from' => string 'ADMIN' (length=5)      public 'joins' => null      public 'wheres' =>         array (size=1)          0 =>             array (size=5)              ...      public 'groups' => null      public 'havings' => null      public 'orders' => null      public 'limit' => null      public 'offset' => null      public 'unions' => null      public 'lock' => null      protected 'backups' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'cacheKey' => null      protected 'cacheMinutes' => null      protected 'cacheTags' => null      protected 'cacheDriver' => null      protected 'operators' =>         array (size=19)          0 => string '=' (length=1)          1 => string '<' (length=1)          2 => string '>' (length=1)          3 => string '<=' (length=2)          4 => string '>=' (length=2)          5 => string '<>' (length=2)          6 => string '!=' (length=2)          7 => string 'like' (length=4)          8 => string 'not like' (length=8)          9 => string 'between' (length=7)          10 => string 'ilike' (length=5)          11 => string '&' (length=1)          12 => string '|' (length=1)          13 => string '^' (length=1)          14 => string '<<' (length=2)          15 => string '>>' (length=2)          16 => string 'rlike' (length=5)          17 => string 'regexp' (length=6)          18 => string 'not regexp' (length=10)  protected 'model' =>     object(Admin)[178]      protected 'table' => string 'ADMIN' (length=5)      protected 'fillable' =>         array (size=1)          0 => string 'EPANTHERID' (length=10)      protected 'connection' => null      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)      protected 'perPage' => int 15      public 'incrementing' => boolean true      public 'timestamps' => boolean true      protected 'attributes' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'original' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'relations' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'hidden' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'visible' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'appends' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'guarded' =>         array (size=1)          0 => string '*' (length=1)      protected 'dates' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'touches' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'observables' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'with' =>         array (size=0)          empty      protected 'morphClass' => null      public 'exists' => boolean false  protected 'eagerLoad' =>     array (size=0)      empty  protected 'macros' =>     array (size=0)      empty  protected 'onDelete' => null  protected 'passthru' =>     array (size=12)      0 => string 'toSql' (length=5)      1 => string 'lists' (length=5)      2 => string 'insert' (length=6)      3 => string 'insertGetId' (length=11)      4 => string 'pluck' (length=5)      5 => string 'count' (length=5)      6 => string 'min' (length=3)      7 => string 'max' (length=3)      8 => string 'avg' (length=3)      9 => string 'sum' (length=3)      10 => string 'exists' (length=6)      11 => string 'getBindings' (length=11)
```

It seems like Eloquent has some mechanism which prevents me from accessing data using var_dump. How could I solve this problem or could anyone show me a better way to debug my php scripts? Thank you.

Comment: use dd($test) instead

Comment: Could you elaborate? I tried. It didn't work

Comment: you got your answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
$test= Admin::where("EPANTHERID","=",$email)->get();
```

or

```
$test= Admin::where("EPANTHERID","=",$email)->first();
```

if `EPANTHERID` is unique and then use `var_dump` on result.

That's because without `get()` or `first()` (and some other methods) you have in your variable only object that holds your query and not the result of running the query (the query in your code has not been launched yet).

Comment: To expand a bit further, Eloquent allows you to build a query before executing it. For example `Model::where('field', 'value')->orderBy('this', 'desc')` would build the query `SELECT * FROM model WHERE field = 'value' ORDER BY this DESC`. You'd then have to run one of the methods such as `take()`, `get()` or `first()` to actually execute the query and return a result.